# Google AutoML Vision not accepting image import

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-automl

I've been using Google Cloud Vision for a while now, and it's been working fine.

However today I log in and try to access my dataset and I see it's been deleted, all my datasets are gone.

So I tried to make a new dataset and it won't let me upload images to the dataset.

I've tried:

- Uploading a zip file of the images
- Uploading a single image
- Creating a new account, new project, new dataset

All these have failed, with the same vague error: "Failed to import data"

Is anyone else having trouble with Google Cloud?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: When you see the "Failed to import data" error, can you see more details about it? I tried to reproduce it and there is a button "View details" at the top. This information could be helpful.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the same vague error message. I also tried changing the IAM permissions for the service but either it's not the issue or I didn't hit the right combination of permissions. So I'm no help unfortunately but I can confirm the issue.

Comment: I also have the same issue, while trying to upload a .csv file which points to the GCS paths.

Comment: It's working today and an old dataset it back too.